# server side values inside customadapter using JSON

Tags: android, json, custom-adapter

//CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

Context context;
int[] imageId = {R.drawable.slider1, R.drawable.slider2};
String[] caption = { "1", "2" };

public CustomAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

    View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    textView.setText(caption[position]);
    ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewItem);

    return viewItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageId.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return view == ((View)object);
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

}
```

my json result is,

```
{
  "slider": [
  {
    "name": "Demo Event",
    "images": "uploads\/event\/demo.png",
    "location": "Ernakulam"
  },
  {
    "name": "cfghedrgyedyg",
    "images": "uploads\/event\/Array466.jpg",
    "location": "dfgred"
  },
  {
    "name": "Demo",
    "images": "uploads\/event\/Array698.jpg",
    "location": "Thodupuzha"
  },
  {
    "name": "Event",
    "images": "uploads\/event\/Array745.jpg",
    "location": "Angamaly"
  },
  {
    "name": "ghtrfhy",
    "images": "uploads\/event\/Array350.jpg",
    "location": "Thodupuzha"
  }
 ]
}
```

my question is, how can I change the values inside `int[] imageId = {R.drawable.slider1, R.drawable.slider2};` and `String[] caption = { "1", "2" };` with the values from the server. ie, using JSON.

Is it possible to implement this.
I tried a lot. But no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your json response

Comment: post you complete cod with network call and all

Comment: @KarthikaPB :- inside this customadapter how can i get the values from server.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi :- `int[] imageId={ "images" field in JSON result }` and `String[] caption = { "name" filed in JSON result }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a business entity/class like this

```
public class ImageDetails()
{
public int ImageId;
public String Caption;
}
```

create a list of this class as object and populate details

```
    List<ImageDetails> imgDetails=new ArrayList<ImageDetails>();

ImageDetails img1=new ImageDetails();
img1.ImageId=1;
img1.Caption="Caption";
```

Change the constructor of your adapter to accept this list

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<ImageDetails> imageDetails){
    this.context = context;
this.ImageDetails=imageDetails;
}
```

Finally in getview

```
TextView textView = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(ImageDetails.get(position).Caption);
```